# Is there a widget that shows free/busy status of one of my Google Calendar calendars?

Tags: calendar, app-widgets

I have, in my Google Calendar account, several calendars which have been shared by friends/family/co-workers.  Is there a widget which I can place on my phone's home page which will show whether or not a given person (or calendar) is "in an appointment" or not?  I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S, but it is running a 2.2 build (Team Whiskey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Android Agenda Widget](http://www.androidagendawidget.com/) is similar in functionality to the LauncherPro calendar widget. It's quite configurable and has a wide range of widget sizes. Also shows tasks from certain supported apps.

Comment: This is certainly in the lead so far :)

Answer (score 3):

Launcher Pro has a nice calendar widget that I use for this purpose.  It can switch back and forth between a month view of the calendar to an agenda view.  I have my own calendar and two other Google calendars hooked in which show up as appointments on my agenda.

Comment: Does that widget work in non Launcher Pro environments?  I'd hate to have to swap out my entire setup for just one widget.

Comment: Sadly, @GWLlosa, I don't believe it does.  Sorry.